# Unity Performance - Referencing a camera from a Worldspace Canvas Prefab to eliminate "FindMainCamera" calls

Tags: unity-game-engine

Looking at the Profiler data, it seems that WorldSpace canvases (I got a bunch of those) who should support click events (they got buttons), are making a lot of calls to `FindMainCamera` through the `EventSystem.Update()` function. I assume this is because all of these canvases are Prefabs and so it isn't trivial for them to get a reference to the active camera from within the editor in prefab mode.

In this project I'm not using Dependency Injection, and I only got one camera in the game, so I was thinking maybe I should just create a `SingletonCamera` component and then have the Prefab canvas reference it.

I do wonder though if there's a better solution, as this seems like a pretty common scenario that a WorldSpace canvas would be inside a prefab, and have no easy access to a camera.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Your call to `FindMainCamera` has barely any impact on performance according to the profile ...

Comment: Thanks @derHugo but then it's the only thing under EventSystem.Update(), with 12 calls in a single frame, and that takes 8.4%. I do however see it says 0.0% for "FindMainCamera", but since it doesn't show anything else under EventSystem.Update(), is there any way to find what might cause this?

Comment: Yes go into the source code and check what else `EventSystem.Update()` is doing internally. Is this already using `deep profile` enabled? If not enable `Deep Profile` and run the same thing again, this should give you detailed information about what exactly is causing delays .. have in mind though that deep profiling again has some performance impact itself ^^

Comment: I had basically the same situation as OP and want to add my two cents here. For me, that call `FindMainCamera` was also 0%, but then I noticed in the Timeline visualization that each call was sequential to the other. Even though returning from the call was almost instantaneous, I had so many of them (almost 10k) that it was enough to all of them combined take like 100ms. I disabled the canvas on my prefabs and confirmed that was the main culprit. I came here to this question hoping for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FindObjectOfType function to get a reference to the active camera at runtime.
This function searches the scene for a component of the specified type and returns the first one it finds.
So, you could add a script to your WorldSpace canvases that uses FindObjectOfType to get a reference to the active camera when the canvas is enabled or when the canvas needs to interact with the camera.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with that is that FindObjectOfType function is considered to be quite expensive and I have a lot of different canvases. On that end, I'd think a better alternative would be to use a Singleton reference.

Comment: Well you would cache that once and then reuse the reference